# Postgesql: Join or Subquery issue

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables `vt_owner, vt_permit, vt_tax`. Common columns are `regn_no, off_Cd` and `state_Cd`.

I want to have all the fields of `vt_owner, vt_permit` and `vt_tax` columns in the result, condition is `(max(vt_tax.tax_upto) > max(permit.vt_permit.valid_upto) and max(permit.vt_permit.valid_upto) < '3-Oct-2019'`

```
SELECT 
  vt_owner.state_cd, vt_owner.off_cd, vt_owner.regn_no, vt_owner.regn_dt, 
  vt_owner.regn_upto, vt_owner.purchase_dt, vt_owner.owner_name, 
  vt_owner.f_name, vt_owner.sale_amt, vt_owner.vh_class,
  vt_owner.maker_model, vt_owner.vch_catg, vt_owner.seat_cap, 
  vt_owner.stand_cap, vt_owner.sleeper_cap,vt_permit.pmt_no, 
  vt_permit.issue_dt, vt_permit.valid_from, vt_permit.valid_upto, 
  vt_permit.pmt_type, vt_permit.pmt_catg, vt_permit.goods_to_carry, 
  vt_tax.tax_mode, vt_tax.rcpt_no, vt_tax.rcpt_dt, vt_tax.tax_from, 
  vt_tax.tax_upto, vt_tax.tax_amt, vt_tax.tax_fine
FROM vt_owner
JOIN permit.vt_permit ON vt_owner.regn_no = permit.vt_permit.regn_no 
                     AND vt_owner.state_cd = permit.vt_permit.state_cd
                     AND vt_owner.off_cd = permit.vt_permit.off_cd
JOIN vt_tax ON vt_owner.regn_no = vt_tax.regn_no 
           AND vt_owner.state_cd = vt_tax.state_cd 
           AND vt_owner.regn_no = vt_tax.regn_no 
WHERE vt_owner.state_cd='JH'
  and (vt_owner.garage_add = 'NULL' OR vt_owner.garage_add = 'NA') 
  AND (vt_owner.status = 'Y' OR vt_owner.status = 'A')
  and max(vt_tax.tax_upto) > max(permit.vt_permit.valid_upto)
  and max(permit.vt_permit.valid_upto) < '3-Oct-2019'
```

Comment: Why do you choose to use archaic syntax instead of proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Comment: these conditions (`(max(vt_tax.tax_upto) > max(permit.vt_permit.valid_upto) and max(permit.vt_permit.valid_upto) < '3-Oct-2019'` ) will not return any significant result. better you provide you requirement in plain text

Comment: Please use modern join syntax, available since SQL-92 (28 years ago). The old syntax you are using is complex to read and to debug.

Comment: In an attemp to help I converted your query to modern join syntax and it's now clear the query is not valid. If you use `MAX()` on some columns you must use `GROUP BY`. The question is now unclear, so I'm voting to close.